# Как разместить бэкенд приложения на хостинге?

Tags: frontend, хостинг, backend, hosting

Я только начинаю публиковать сайт и не очень разбираюсь в этом.
Клиентскую часть приложения на хостинг(fornex) я вроде бы залил. Но у меня также есть серверная часть приложения на C#, отвечающая за логику работы сайта. Что мне нужно сделать чтобы их подружить? VPS арендовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, арендованный VPS решает, конечно, все проблемы. ( Как было хорошо, когда Oracle предоставлял в своём облаке бесплатную неограниченную по времени использования машинку с 24 гигами оперативки! )

Но, с другой стороны, это выглядит для многих случаев как стрельба из пушки по воробьям.

В большинстве случаев, серверную часть можно упаковать в docker-image и запустить его на каком то хостинге, который разрешает запуск docker-контейнеров.

Еще один варинат - "домашний хостинг", например, в таком варианте: у Вас есть "фронтэнд", расположенный на домене второго уровня, что то типа mysite.ru. Он в своём коде обращается в к "бэкэнду", расположенному, к примеру, на backend.mysite.ru. А этот адрес - уже указывает на Ваш домашний комп, на котором запущена "серверная часть". Это вполне подходит для небольших или учебных проектов, хотя, конечно, требует решения нескольких проблем: как мне кажется, нужно будет научится настраивать CORS - policy, разобраться с расшариваанием портов на роутере и вообще с тем, как это всё хостить.

Еще один очень интересный вариант - это "[лямбды](https://habr.com/ru/post/648885/)", ну и вообще - погружение в мир AWS или Microsoft Azure сервисов. Но это - не совсем та штука, которой хочется заниматься в начале, пока еще учишься.

Поэтому, совет такой: если нужно "быстро, но не дёшево" - просто возьмите VPS - хостинг, с полноценным линуксом, на котором можно всё настроить. Можно такой хостинг брать один на несколько проектов или несколько человек.

Если берёте хостинг начального уровня (как правило, сильно ограниченный по памяти) - обратите внимание на дистрибутивчик [Alpine](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux). А то, загрузится на таком маленьком хостинге какая нибудь убунта, и "съест" половину оперативки.

Если Вы хахотите "слезть с этой иглы" - попробуйте разобраться, как сделать "то же самое, но своими руками".